# Leaflet - How to match marker and polyline on drag and drop #2 (delete the last marker and polyline with button click)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, drag, marker, polyline

I stuck again.
Putting the markers and connecting them is working. Thanks to "Falke Design" :-)
Now I would like to remove the last marker (Waypoint), when I click on the "Delete last Waypoint" button.
I manged to do it and working well, but the last line is not removed.
Full code You can find here:
[Demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/steger/dpke0ns5/12/)

This issue shall be in
function delteLastWp()
row # 218

```
function delteLastWp(id) { 

    var new_markers = []
    marker_new.forEach(function(marker) {
        if (marker._id == id) {
            map.removeLayer(marker);
        }
        else new_markers.push(marker)
    })
    marker_new = new_markers

    // remove the last point/line in the polyline as well ! 
    var new_polylines = []  
    tempLine.forEach(function(polyline) {
        if (polyline._id == id) {
            map.removeLayer(polyline); //*** This si not working ****
            // remove the last point in the polyline as well !
        }
        else new_polylines.push(polyline)
    })      
}
```

Please help me! Thank You very much in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
function delteLastWp()  // ## with the last segment of the polyline 
{ //marker_new[lineCount]

    var new_markers = []
    marker_new.forEach(function(marker) {
        if (marker._id == lineCount) {
            map.removeLayer(marker);  // Working :-)
      lineCount--;
        }
        else new_markers.push(marker)
    })
    marker_new = new_markers;

    var latlngs = tempLine.getLatLngs()
    latlngs.splice(-1); 
    tempLine.setLatLngs(latlngs);
        
}
```

You load the latlngs from the line, then remove the last latlng and then add it again to the tempLine